# Show that the values of the following determinants are not zero without actually finding the exact values

Tags: matrices, determinant, matrix-equations, gaussian-elimination

$$\begin{bmatrix}
111 & 100 & 225 & 235\\
220 & 312 & 220 & 410\\
215 & 180 & 268 & 305\\
315 & 145 & 205 & 122
\end{bmatrix}$$

Guys is it enough to show that after Gaussian elimination whether we get lower/upper triangle we also get non zero diagonal entries ($a_{11}$,$a_{22}$,$a_{33}$,$a_{44}$), therefore determinant is the multiplication of these entries. Thus determinant is not zero.

Comment: This is 4 x 4 square matrix.

Comment: Think modulo $5$.

Comment: Find rank of matrix

Comment: Is it possible to show without rank?

Comment: Reducing modulo $3$ also works.